# CSS for checkbox not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, checkbox

This code in a wordpress site:

```
<div class="form_row checkbox_list">
    <input type="checkbox" name="HotelTypeIDs[]2" id="hotel-type-hotel2" value="0" <?php echo (in_array(1, $hoteltypeids) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?>>huh</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="HotelTypeIDs[]" id="hotel-type-hotel" value="1" <?php echo (in_array(1, $hoteltypeids) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?>/>

    <label for="hotel-type-hotel">Hotels</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="HotelTypeIDs[]" id="hotel-type-condoresort" value="2" <?php echo (in_array(2, $hoteltypeids) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?>/>
    <label for="hotel-type-condoresort">Condos/Resorts</label>
</div>
```

Is creating checkboxes being styled by this:

```
/* Checkbox */ 

#form_search form .checkbox_list {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#form_search form .checkbox_list input {
    clear:left;
    border:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    width:18px;
    height:17px;
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
#form_search form .checkbox_list label {
    background:none;
    font: 400 1.15em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    float:none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 5px;
    padding:5px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
div.checker, div.checker span {
    background: url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
div.checker span {
    background-position:0px -194px;
}
div.checker:active span, div.checker.active span {
    background-position:-19px -194px
}
div.checker.focus span, div.checker:hover span {
    background-position:-38px -194px
}
div.checker.focus:active span, div.checker:active:hover span, div.checker.active:hover span, div.checker.focus.active span {
    background-position:-57px -194px
}
div.checker span.checked {
    background-position:-76px -194px
}
div.checker:active span.checked, div.checker.active span.checked {
    background-position:-95px -194px
}
div.checker.focus span.checked, div.checker:hover span.checked {
    background-position:-114px -194px
}
div.checker.focus:active span.checked, div.checker:hover:active span.checked, div.checker.active:hover span.checked, div.checker.active.focus span.checked {
    background-position:-133px -194px
}
div.checker.disabled span, div.checker.disabled:active span, div.checker.disabled.active span {
    background-position:-152px -194px
}
div.checker.disabled span.checked, div.checker.disabled:active span.checked, div.checker.disabled.active span.checked {
    background-position:-171px -194px
}
```

The checkboxes are not being checked in ie unless you click away from them.

I would like to simply have standard checkboxes if this will resolve this.

You can see this at ohpark.sportsrez.com.

Comment: Please format your code. What version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: i am trying to format the code its driving me nuts

Comment: removed code i will try to add the css again, the css is causing the issue

Comment: OK it's fixed now - which version of IE are you testing in? And which browsers does your code currently work in?

Comment: thank you, ie 11 windows 8, it works in chrome

Comment: I can tell you one thing for sure, and it's that styling checkboxes can be very annoying. Some browsers have absolute styling on them which can't be overwritten.

Comment: I didn't write this code and could use advice on how to make it simply display simple checkboxes without all the bells and whistles.

Comment: nobody can help with this or ask more questions?

Comment: I give up on this place!

Answer (score 0):

The code here:
    div.checker.focus:active span, div.checker:active:hover span, div.checker.active:hover span, div.checker.focus.active span {
    background-position:-57px -194px

Was only being read by IE and was not moving the sprite over far enough.

Changing the -57 to -76 did the trick.